# keyboard input for paint method(joption pane)

Tags: java, swing, input, jpanel, paintcomponent

help im frustrated, cant find an input scanner method for joption pane. I need to read user input from the dialog box, but my in = a.nextInt fail to work. which if after (input = 1), certain shape will be drawn,  what is the code to scan dialog input can anyone help

```
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.util.Scanner;
public class Paint extends JPanel {


public Paint() {

    Scanner a = new Scanner(System.in);
     in = a.nextInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Please enter number: "));

    setBackground(Color.WHITE);

}
public void paintComponent(Graphics g){
    super.paintComponent(g);



    if(in == 1){
    g.setColor(Color.BLACK);
    g.drawLine(400, 400, 400, 350);
    g.drawLine(400, 350, 350, 350);
    }
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use next construction :

```
int in = -1;
String showInputDialog = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Please enter number: ");
try{
    in = Integer.valueOf(showInputDialog);
} catch (Exception e){
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

instead of

```
Scanner a = new Scanner(System.in);
in = a.nextInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Please enter number: "));
```